# CreateNamedPipe failed with ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED for untrusted integrity process

Tags: winapi, pipe, ipc

I am implementing inter-process communication with named pipe, when it comes to untrusted integrity level processes(e.g. some child processes of chrome), CreateNamedPipe(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-createnamedpipea) fails with ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED. I wonder if there is anything wrong with security descriptor?

```
static VOID BuildDACL(PSECURITY_DESCRIPTOR pDescriptor)
{
    PSID pSid;
    EXPLICIT_ACCESS ea;
    PACL pAcl;

    SID_IDENTIFIER_AUTHORITY sia = SECURITY_WORLD_SID_AUTHORITY;

    AllocateAndInitializeSid(&sia, 1, SECURITY_WORLD_RID, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
        &pSid);

    ZeroMemory(&ea, sizeof(EXPLICIT_ACCESS));
    ea.grfAccessPermissions = FILE_ALL_ACCESS;
    ea.grfAccessMode = SET_ACCESS;
    ea.grfInheritance = NO_INHERITANCE;
    ea.Trustee.TrusteeForm = TRUSTEE_IS_SID;
    ea.Trustee.TrusteeType = TRUSTEE_IS_WELL_KNOWN_GROUP;
    ea.Trustee.ptstrName = (LPTSTR)pSid;

    if (SetEntriesInAcl(1, &ea, NULL, &pAcl) == ERROR_SUCCESS)
    {
        if (SetSecurityDescriptorDacl(pDescriptor, TRUE, pAcl, FALSE) == 0)
            _tprintf(_T("[*] Failed to set DACL (%u)\n"), GetLastError());
    }
    else
        _tprintf(_T("[*] Failed to add ACE in DACL (%u)\n"), GetLastError());
}


/* Create a SACL that will allow low integrity processes connect to our pipe. */
static VOID BuildSACL(PSECURITY_DESCRIPTOR pDescriptor)
{
    PSID pSid;
    PACL pAcl;

    SID_IDENTIFIER_AUTHORITY sia = SECURITY_MANDATORY_LABEL_AUTHORITY;
    DWORD dwACLSize = sizeof(ACL) + sizeof(SYSTEM_MANDATORY_LABEL_ACE) +
        GetSidLengthRequired(1);

    pAcl = (PACL)LocalAlloc(LPTR, dwACLSize);
    InitializeAcl(pAcl, dwACLSize, ACL_REVISION);

    AllocateAndInitializeSid(&sia, 1, SECURITY_MANDATORY_LOW_RID, 0, 0, 0, 0,
        0, 0, 0, &pSid);

    if (AddMandatoryAce(pAcl, ACL_REVISION, 0, SYSTEM_MANDATORY_LABEL_NO_WRITE_UP,
        pSid) == TRUE)
    {
        if (SetSecurityDescriptorSacl(pDescriptor, TRUE, pAcl, FALSE) == 0)
            _tprintf(_T("[*] Failed to set SACL (%u)\n"), GetLastError());
    }
    else
        _tprintf(_T("[*] Failed to add ACE in SACL (%u)\n"), GetLastError());
}

static VOID InitSecurityAttributes(PSECURITY_ATTRIBUTES pAttributes)
{
    PSECURITY_DESCRIPTOR pDescriptor;

    pDescriptor = (PSECURITY_DESCRIPTOR)LocalAlloc(LPTR,
        SECURITY_DESCRIPTOR_MIN_LENGTH);
    InitializeSecurityDescriptor(pDescriptor, SECURITY_DESCRIPTOR_REVISION);

    BuildDACL(pDescriptor);
    BuildSACL(pDescriptor);

    pAttributes->nLength = sizeof(SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES);
    pAttributes->lpSecurityDescriptor = pDescriptor;
    pAttributes->bInheritHandle = TRUE;
}

DWORD initIpc()
{
    SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES sa;
    InitSecurityAttributes(&sa);
    HANDLE pipe = CreateNamedPipe(_MYIPC_NAME_, PIPE_ACCESS_INBOUND | PIPE_ACCESS_OUTBOUND, PIPE_WAIT, 1, sizeof(IPC_MESSAGE), sizeof(IPC_MESSAGE), 60 * 1000, &sa);
    if (pipe == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        // ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED
        return 0;
    }
...
}
```

Comment: besides something wrong with the security descriptor, *All instances of a named pipe must specify the same pipe type (byte-type or message-type), pipe access (duplex, inbound, or outbound), instance count, and time-out value. If different values are used, this function fails and GetLastError returns ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED.*

Comment: How does the named pipe cooperate with untrusted integrity level processes(e.g. some child processes of chrome)?

Comment: i don't think any of other parameters are wrong, because it works for medium privilege processes.

Comment: the interesting thing is it works when i call CreateNamedPipe from dllmain, and fails in a separate thread.